# If an electron is an elementary particle, where is charge "stored"?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, electrons, antimatter, elementary-particles

In particular, how can you have both positrons and electrons if there is no "bit" to set or unset?

I hope this is not a stupid question, but if a particle has no internal structure, where can the difference between the electron and its antiparticle exist?

If it is due to something "external", like spin (if indeed spin is external), how do we know we can't change this by applying some external influence -- change then an electron into a positron somehow?

Comment: Classical physics and quantum mechanics do not contain an explanation for this. This is one of the things people hope to get out of String Theory.

Comment: It's not a stupid question. On the contrary, it is one of the most brilliant questions I have seen lately.

Comment: It would be horribly inefficient if every electron had to store the same value $q=-1$.

Comment: There are recent models of [electron inner structure](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation?paperid=122485), check c-ring.

Comment: Keep in mind that the standard model  (SM)of physics at present uses the definition "elementary particle" because these are **axiomatic** definitions for the quantum field models of the SM . Over the past century the mathematics of SM have been continually changing in orde for the model to be correct in predictions and descriptions of  measurements and observations. This is where we are now, that the axiomatic definitions of elementary particles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle is descriptive and predictive of measurements and observations using the SM .

Answer (score 3):

The *full* information about all properties of (free) electrons and positrons is "stored" in the (quantum) *field operator* $$\psi(x) =\sum\limits_s \int d\mu(p) \left[ b(p,s) u(p,s) e^{-ip\cdot x}+ d(p,s) v(p,s) e^{i p\cdot x} \right], \tag{1} \label{1}$$ being *always* "present" at any time-space point $x=(t, \vec{x})$ and *independently* of the actual *state* of the system (e.g. vacuum = no particle present, one electron present, one positron present, 153 electrons and 2 positrons present, and infinitely more possibilities).

Although the fermion field operator \eqref{1} is not directly observable, the operators representing the measurable quantities of the system (observables) are obtained from \eqref{1} by building (bosonic) functionals like $$Q= -e\int d^3x\, : \psi^\dagger(x) \psi(x): \tag{2} \label{2}$$ for the charge or $$P^\mu =\int d^3x : \psi^\dagger(x) i \partial^\mu \psi(x): \tag{3} \label{3}$$ for the total energy $P^0$ and the total momentum $\vec{P}$.

If a certain (pure) *state* $| \chi\rangle$ (out of the infinitely many possible ones) of the system is realized, the expectation value of an observable $A$ is obtained by computing $\langle \chi |A|\chi \rangle$. Let us take the most general one-electron state $$|\chi\rangle = \sum\limits_s \int d\mu(p) f(p,s) b^\dagger (p,s) |0\rangle \tag{4} \label{4}$$ as an example. In this case, we have $\langle \chi |Q |\chi \rangle =-e$ and $\langle \chi |P^\mu |\chi \rangle = \sum\limits_s \int d\mu(p) |f(p,s)|^2 p^\mu$, and analogously for other observables.

Comment: Since there is no doubt that QED provides an excellent (i.e. experimentally tested to high precision) description of electrons, positrons and the EM field, this is THE answer. Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106605/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109535/226902

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that information have size.When we say that e.g a latch stores a bit we are refering to the output voltage level.How does the latch store the voltage level?The transistors inside the gate conduct or not current and by voltage division we get the output value.But the information itself isnt something you can hold on.Information is not a physical thing.

Comment: I think the idea that information does not have a minimum size would be disputed.

Comment: @releseabe does conciousness have a size?Its the same thing.

Comment: @releseabe you are in the realm of ideas.  Ideas don't have a size or a mass, and they are not subject to the standard laws of physics.

Comment: I remember (reference needed) some discussion on hardware and how small it can get to store one bit without collapsing into a tiny black hole.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Indeed, the Bekenstein bound. For 1 bit I believe it is $\sqrt{hG\log 2/c^3} \approx$ 3.4e-35 m.

Answer (score 0):

> if a particle has no internal structure, where can the difference
> between the electron and its antiparticle exist?

Your premise does not seem correct: a physical electron does have internal structure, as evidenced by vacuum polarization and electron's Coulomb field, which field carries at least a part of the mass of the physical electron. I wrote elsewhere:

> My understanding is: when people say that elementary particles, such
> as electrons, are point particles, they mean that they are described
> by the Dirac equation / QED with great accuracy. The Nobel prize
> winner Dehmelt, who established strong experimental limitations on the
> size of the electron, wrote (Physica Scripta. Vol. T22, 102-110,
> 1988): "an elementary Dirac particle, such as the electron, is the
> closest laboratory approximation of a point particle."

And the Dirac particle is subject to uncertainty principle. Moreover, if the coordinate of the Dirac particle is measured better than the Compton wavelength, we cannot be sure we have just one particle because of possible pair production.

> If it is due to something "external", like spin (if indeed spin is
> external), how do we know we can't change this by applying some
> external influence -- change then an electron into a positron somehow?

I would say, because of experimental evidence of charge conservation.