# Do charges attractions cause time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, charge, time-dilation

I was pondering whether charges will cause time dilatation? Let me explain more, well we know that gravity causes time-dilatation because of gravitational acceleration which is equal to: $$a = \frac{G* m_1}{r^2}$$

That said we can say if we say since the $a$ does not get stronger with time we can say substitute $a$ in Special Relativistic effects so we can get the relativistic results although small it can still show some scientific significance anyhow similarly we can use 2 opposite charges and simply gain the acceleration and we will get $$a = \frac{q_1* q_2* k}{r^2*m_2}$$

This shows that since charges will also have an "charge acceleration" we can also say since the acceleration is constant and does not increase with time we could also substitute into special relativistic environment. to get results, so would this thought process me correct or am I incorrect in saying this?

If so can somebody explain to me what is incorrect assumptions or thought processes?

Comment: Ignore relativity for a second here, why do you think it is okay to write $v=a$?  When is is ever okay to write 2 centimeters equals 2 liters? The answer is never.  Acceleration and velocity are two distinct things that are never equal.  You must understand this before going further.

Comment: @kηives I have edited this out, if you are unhappy can you edit it, thanks!

Comment: Special Relativity (for flat, Lorentzian spacetime) can describe acceleration, and indeed there are effects.  You should be able to find a treatment in a intro relativity textbook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is spacetime curved by mass but not charge?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111761/)