# Why does a charged black hole affect the trajectories and event horizon for uncharged particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, spacetime, charge, reissner-nordstrom-metric

I can get electric charge affecting the behavior of quarks, charged leptons, W bosons, and photons since they interact electromagnetically. However, why would it affect uncharged particles like the Higgs boson, Z boson, neutrinos, and whatever dark matter turns out to be? Shouldn't they perceive a black hole with mass $M$ and charge $Q$ as just a black hole with mass $M$ and an event horizon at  $2GM/c^2$ instead of the reduced value a Reissner–Nordström metric has?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is spacetime curved by mass but not charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111761/)

Comment: I would think that the Electromagnetic field of the black hole carries energy as well and therefore sources gravity as well.

Comment: The question linked as a "duplicate" (and its answers) does not actually answer this question. The question here can be paraphrases "Why is the Reissner–Nordström metric different from the Schwarzschild metric?" while the answers to the linked question can be paraphrased as "charge does effect the curvature because the Reissner–Nordström metric is different from the Schwarzschild metric". It is quite clear that the OP is aware of this last fact. Lets do better.