# Can Electromagnetism affect Gravity?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity

We know Gravity affects Electromagnetism when we see Black Holes bending the light around them. That makes me wonder if Electromagnetism Can Effect Gravity?

Just like how $E=mc^2$ means energy and mass are equal, I’m guessing if one can affect the other than vise versa can be applied as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is spacetime curved by mass but not charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111761/)

Comment: I know that this question has been answered on this site before but I can't find it.

But yes electromagnetic fields have an energy density and pressures associated with them, and this means that they can act as gravitational sources.