# Composition of energy of electron?

Tags: electrons, electric-fields, mass-energy

Mass energy of electron is 0.510 998 9461MeV/ c2

1) Does it include energy of electron due to electric field too?

2) If yes, how much?

I am more interested in second part.

Links:[Here John Rennie says:](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61261/do-objects-have-energy-because-of-their-charge)

> Nevertheless, you could use the above reasoning to claim that a charged electron actually has a lower energy than an uncharged one would. Now there's an unexpected result :-)

Can anyone tell how much exact less energy it will have?

Or is it just, we can't because we don't have uncharged electron.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel The relativistic mass is an obsolete concept, mass/inertia is invariant under Lorentz transformations

Comment: The charge is an invariant quantity. Then  how could it emit more electric field? The mass varying equation has no physical significance. The best way to see it as the relativistic momentum. For a relativistically moving charged particle, it's the momentum that varies relativistically:$ p=mv_0=mv/\gamma$. That variation is solely due to the difference between proper velocity and ordinary velocity

Comment: @ACuriousMind and others: whats not clear?

Comment: @JohnRennie: Is it clear now?

Comment: @MAFIA36790 : What is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

There is the concept of the self energy of the electron that can be described by its electric field. The model, which goes back to classical physics, can be described as a spherically distributed charges (that equal the charge of the electron) at infinity and the work required to bring the charges to the radius of the electron. The calculation would show the total energy of the electron due to its own charge and ensuing electric field. The standard model describes the electron as a point charge. If you do this calculation to a zero point, the electron would have infinite mass, however we know what it should be. The calculated radius however is much larger that the upper limit of the electron radius as measured in high energy probe experiments into subatomic particles. The electron should have much more mass due to its own self energy of its own electric field. This is a big puzzle and renormalization techniques are used to arrive at the mass of the electron. Feynman did a lot of work in this area and spends quite some time describing it in his Nobel Prize speech.

Comment: Has some result been founded now?

Comment: Modern quantum field theory has some answers. There is the concept of the polarization of the vacuum surrounding the electron due to the filed of virtual particle pairs that surround the electron. This tends to smear out the charge to a larger radius. Uncertainty principle at work.

Comment: can you please give a link for *renormalization techniques*

Comment: This Wikipedia article explains the issues fairly well, especially for the electron, although the math behind it may be somewhat advancced for you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization

Comment: *" The electron should have much more mass due to its own self energy of its own electric field. This is a big puzzle and renormalization techniques are used to arrive at the mass of the electron. " * Can you please tell how much more mass does it have than self energy of electric field?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I can't think of any reason why an increase in the mass of an electrically charged object should affect the magnitude of the electric field it produces. You can easily check that $E=kq/r^2$ doesn't depend on $m$. Moving charges do produce magnetic fields, but this is a different matter (and the magnitude of the magnetic field has nothing to do with the mass of the object, neither).

On the other hand, as it was noted in the comments, [mass](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) is a Lorentz scalar, then a relativistic invariant quantity (i. e., it is the same on any reference frame). In fact, the Minkowski norm (length) of the 4-momentum is $p^{\mu} p_{\mu}= -m^2c^2$. Only the *components* of a 4-vector are modified when subject to Lorentz transformations, never its norm.

**Edit:** To sum up, as far as I know charge/electric field doesn't affect to the mass/energy of any charged object, is it moving or at rest. By "electric energy" you might be referring to the [electric potential energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elepe.html) or to the [electric field density](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/engfie.html), you can see that both concepts are unrelated with mass.

Comment: That was my first question *does energy of electron include electric field energy as well.* If electric energy comes from mass energy , increase in mass can cause increase in charge and hence electric field.

Comment: Where did you get that "electric energy" (I don't exactly know what are you referring to) comes from mass? There's no increase in mass, that's what I just argued.

Comment: That's what I asked *does above energy I mentioned in question includes energy in electric field around charge.*

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Does the edit clarify my answer/satisfy your doubts?

Comment: Nop!  It would be better if you can answer my first question

Comment: "Does it include energy of electron due to electric field too?" No, it doesn't. I've already explained why (again, see the edit). Where is the problem?

Comment: In classical physics mass energy was equated to electrical energy to find out radius of electron. Although, radius resulted was wrong, they equated two. Why? Does not that mean all mass energy is electric field energy.

Comment: Can you give a source for the derivation you're citing?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electron_radius

Answer (score 0):

> 2) Does it include energy of electron due to electric field too?

We do not know. If the electron was composed of charged elementary parts, its apparent inertial mass would be greater than sum of inertial masses of the parts. This is because such parts will act on each other with electromagnetic forces and in accelerated motion, sum of these internal forces is not zero, but can be expressed as $-m_{em}\mathbf a$, where $m_{em}$ is a positive number. This force can be put next to the expression $m\mathbf a$ in the equation of motion to get the approximate equation

$$
(m+m_{em})\mathbf a = \mathbf F_{ext}.
$$

Hence $m_{em}$ is called electromagnetic mass(for slow motions of charged sphere, this was derived by Lorentz). The apparent mass $m+m_{em}$ will be greater than sum of individual masses $m$.

If the electron was a point and therefore not composed of parts, there would be no such effect, for there are no internal forces due to any parts.

It is necessary that at least part of apparent mass is non-electromagnetic; for electron made of parts, non-electromagnetic forces need to be present to keep the parts of electron together and these forces probably have some similar effect on the apparent mass; for point electron, there are no mutual electromagnetic forces at all, so they cannot result in any change in apparent mass.

Comment: Please see the reference to the self energy of the electron, which is an elementry particle with no other stucture.

Comment: Which one? What is the point?

Comment: I don't understand the comment. Are you saying that the electron does not interact with its own electric field?

Comment: No, I was asking which reference did you mean and why do you suggest it. Still, to answer your question, in case of point electron in vacuum, I do not think it makes sense to talk about self-interaction, the common rationale for it (Larmor formula for radiated energy, limiting radius of extended particle to 0) is misguided. Self-interaction only makes sense for extended objects. For point-particle, it can also make sense if it is meant to be effective description of interaction with actual material medium. But not if the particle is alone in vacuum.

Comment: How do you explain electromagnetic radiation from accelerating electrons in space?

Comment: Radiation of electrons can be explained as solution of Maxwell's equations with accelerating charged points, no self-interaction is needed.

Comment: If you don't take electrons as composed of sub parts, it's fine. But , that's not question. Electric field has energy, mass has energy. Total energy= mass + electric. Question is , Is 0.5 mass energy, electric or total

Comment: @PeterR, to address your probable concern more directly, existence of electromagnetic radiation in theory follows from Maxwell's equations, which are well established and reliable base of theory. The same cannot be said about self-interaction of point particles. Luckily, use and application of the former for point particles does not need the latter in any way.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel, I do not know if electrons are points or not. The answer to your question is no EM mass if they are points, and part of mass is electromagnetic if they are extended charged bodies. As far as I know, we do not know which is more accurate picture of the real electrons, because there is no experiment known that could distinguish between particle and extended body of small enough dimensions, and there is also no known experiment that could measure how much mass is electromagnetic mass.